# How Can I Transform An Int Into Html

Tags: elm

I am writing a small program that handles and displays **guitar chords**.

But I got stuck: I don't know how to **convert** an Int value into Html.

---

My little **render function** looks like:

```
renderGuitarString : GuitarString -> Html Msg
renderGuitarString guitarString =
    div [ class "string" ] --here I don't know what to do
```

and:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] (List.map renderGuitarString model.guitarStrings)
```

---

just for the complete picture, my **types** and my **model**:

```
type alias GuitarString =
{   number : Int
,   frets : List Fret
}
```

and:

```
type alias Fret =
    {   number : Int
    ,   tone : ( String, Int )
    }
```

and:

```
type alias Model =
    {   guitarStrings : List GuitarString
    }
```

---

I want to transform the **Fret** number value into real Html.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: this will not work in Elm 0.19, use [String.fromInt](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#fromInt) instead

You use `Html.text` to display a string, but the problem is that an integer is not a string, so you'll have to use `toString`. For example:

```elm
renderGuitarStringNum : Int -> Html Msg
renderGuitarStringNum num =
    text (toString num)
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, toString did not work and may be outdated. But String.fromInt did.

Comment: With elm 19 I can confirm that the previous answers no longer work, and that this should now be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also render that as

```
renderGuitarStringNum = toString >> text
```

Or

```
renderGuitarStringNum = text << toString
```